# login form in iphone native application

Tags: iphone, authentication, interface-builder, passwords, uitextfield

I am trying to do the login form I have created two uitextfields for username ,password and one uibutton for login. when I enter password in password textfield I want to display all the text as '*' or any special characters like in the following images

[image] 
[image]

Is there any default ways in sdk to do this or we have to do it logically if any give me some sample codes?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The UITextInputField conforms to the UITextInputTraits protocol, which means you can use the following to tell it to display "*"s:

```
[passwordTextInputField setSecureTextEntry:YES];
```

Answer (score 3):

Open you NIB-File in Interface-Builder, mark your UITextField and open the Inspector (Tools > Inspector). In the very left Tab (Attributes) set the value of "Secure" to TRUE.

See the Screenshot below:

[image]

Programmaticaly you can use the following line of Code:

```
password.secureTextEntry = TRUE
```

Where password is your UITextField.

Comment: You need to change `TRUE` to `YES` as in the example by John Franklin when doing it programatically. Like so `password.secureTextEntry = YES`.

Comment: Both will work, no matter if you write `TRUE` or `YES`. Both are valid boolean values. It's only a matter of personal preferences.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [myTextField setSecureTextEntry:YES] which is part of the UITextInputTraits protocol whom UITextField adhere.

Don't know of a "free" way to change the secure character, though.